# Check if someone write in field and than block this field for others

Tags: jquery, ajax

**Situation**: i have an input field where user can write some text

**Problem**: It's should be allowed to write only in order one after other. So if someone is already by writting, the field should be blocked for all other user.

Is there some possible solution for such Issue across jQuery/Ajax?

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: Sorry, but you can't do it with jQuery only. You should use long-polling or websockets, for example.

Comment: By using AJAX, you could accomplish this by sending an AJAX request on each focus/unfocus on the desired field and then updating some sort of field database on the backend server. Then, you would need a polling script that constantly checks the backend database (AJAX, also) and which lets you edit fields based on the values from this database. This is what I could think of by using AJAX. I am sure there are better ways of doing this with some other technologies.

Comment: You tagged your question with [tag:ajax], but you need some back-end for that. Do you use PHP, ASP or some other server-side language?

Comment: If “other users” means people using the same page on a different computer, then no, this is not solvable using client-side techniques alone.

Comment: Im using PHP for server side.

Comment: First Comment with long-polling and websocket seems to be the right way. I have to research in this direction. Thanks a lot.